# How to run .profile inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have to SU first and  run a profile inside a script, when I ran below script..the profile is giving log to the terminal and the parameters resolved in profiel or not resolving for the next line.thanks in advance

```
if [ $owner = "user1" ]
then
    su -c " . ~/.profile; cd $LOG_DOR; cat $job.log" - user1
else
    echo "$owner not found"
fi
```

Comment: Are `$LOG_DOR` and `$job` defined in the current script, or by ~/.profile? Since they're in double-quotes here, they'll be expanded in script context before the command string is passed to the `su` command.

Comment: They're defined in . profile, How can I overcome it?

Comment: You could single quote the command, or use `su -` to start a a login shell.

Answer (score 2):

To read in a file to the current shell, use `source`

```
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

When the shell parses a double-quoted string, it does variable expansion on the contents (replacing `$varname` with the variable's value) before executing the command. In this case, since the `LOG_DOR` and `job` variables are defined in ~/.profile (and *not* in the script) and that means that

```
su -c " . ~/.profile; cd $LOG_DOR; cat $job.log" - user1
```

will be expanded to:

```
su -c " . ~/.profile; cd ; cat .log" - user1
```

Which isn't what you want at all. To defer expansion of the variables, you can use single-quotes instead of double:

```
su -c ' . ~/.profile; cd $LOG_DOR; cat $job.log' - user1
```

But I'll actually recommend a couple of other changes as well: Put double-quotes around the variable references, to avoid possible problems when they do get expanded, and join the commands with `&&` (instead of `;`) so that if one fails it skips the rest (rather than blindly trying to continue):

```
su -c '. ~/.profile && cd "$LOG_DOR" && cat "$job.log"' - user1
```

EDIT: apparently in this case `job` is defined in the script, and `LOG_DOR` in ~/.profile; therefore the expansion of `$job` should be done immediately, and `$JOB_DOR` deferred. Fortunately, it's possible to use double-quotes and escape (`\`) the `$` for expansions you want deferred. You'll also need to escape some other special characters, like included double-quotes (which would end the string if not escaped). Here, I've also switched to single-quotes around the `$job` reference, in case it contains any special characters that'd otherwise cause trouble (although this will fail if it contains any single-quotes itself):

```
su -c ". ~/.profile && cd \"\$LOG_DOR\" && cat '$job.log'" - user1
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon for the detailed solution

Comment: Getting more critical..now the problem is `"$LOG_DOR"` is from ~/. profile and `"$job"` is defined in the script. Any solution for this?

Comment: Got the solution.. instead of just initialisation I exported `export $job=$1`